# Select a subset of a Mat and copy them to create a new mat in C++/Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, mat

In C++/opencv, how can I select a subset of a big Mat and copy them to create a new Mat? I know how to use copyto, colrange, rowrange, etc., but don't know to combine them together to develop a decent and efficient code. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Mat::clone()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use  [copyTo()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto) for this purpose:

```
//copy a sub matrix of X to Y with starting coodinate (startX,startY)
// and dimension (cols,rows)
cv::Mat tmp = X(cv::Rect(startX,startY,cols,rows));
cv::Mat Y;
tmp.copyTo(Y);
```

or directly:

```
cv::Mat Y;
X(cv::Rect(startX,startY,cols,rows)).copyTo(Y);
```