# How to read in a certain number of rows into a Mat object from an XML file (OpenCV)?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I am looking to read in a certain number of rows from an xml file into a mat object. For example looking at the xml file below, I wish to only read 10,000 rows of the data. I would then like to store the 10,000 rows into a mat object of size (10000,95,CV_32F);

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<featureVector type_id="opencv-matrix">
   <rows>34381</rows>
   <cols>95</cols>
   <dt>f</dt>
   <data>
    1.44965559e-001 9.77574438e-002 5.78284226e-002 2.95825675e-002
    2.90913619e-002 4.95372787e-002 5.18676676e-002 1.07530527e-001
    6.14087284e-002 1.18194185e-001 5.44071913e-001 3.08346570e-001
    4.71893772e-002 5.77269197e-002 1.99747104e-002 7.79013662e-003
    1.93754639e-002 1.56246489e-002 1.07879408e-001 6.43140554e-001
    3.08369696e-001 5.67582771e-002 6.82025328e-002 1.12302238e-002
    1.19626308e-002 2.68770847e-002 1.13766259e-002 3.16501665e-003
    5.22044823e-002 8.28718115e-003 8.87764909e-004 1.62017101e-003
    ............
```

So the code That I have to read in the entire XML data to a mat object is the following:

```
 Mat posData
 FileStorage pos("C:/.../posSamps.xml", FileStorage::READ);
 pos["featureVector"] >> posData;
```

Is there anyway I can limit this to a specific number of rows instead of reading all of the data from the xml file?

Comment: please provide some code. Stackoverflow is here to answer questions about source code. Not to provide the source code. --> What kind of object do you want? What is this Mat object? What XML parser do you use? ...

Comment: I understand its here to answer questions and this is a source code question. The Mat object as the title says is an OpenCv Mat object. But for your liking I'll provide some openCV code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are really HW constrained it will be easier and faster to have opencv read the entire cv::Mat and then use a [region of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691079/select-a-subset-of-a-mat-and-copy-them-to-create-a-new-mat-in-c-opencv) to copy the the subset of rows into another mat.

Comment: Well for another file I have It's very large and taking a while to read in the whole file. Thats why I was only hoping to only read in a smaller portion, for testing, which hopefully will be faster.

Comment: Most XML readers will read and parse the entire file into a tree structure before giving you access. Unless you want to open the file as raw text and read each of the floats until you have 95cols*10,000*rows.

Comment: No I definitely don't want to do that, I thought it might be an easier way of doing it with an opencv filenodeiterator.

Comment: As somebody said: you have a problem, you decide to use xml, now you have 2 problems ;-)