# OpenCV: manipulating different images of the same type to all look the same

Tags: opencv

I have a large set of images which are cellphone photos taken of driver’s licenses (but this could apply to any type of document).  They come in all shapes and sizes, meaning, different angles of the camera, different distances from the camera to the driver’s license, different lighting, etc.

Is there any way in OpenCV to identify in each image a known landmark, then crop, resize, rotate each image so that for the final result, I have a set of images that are completely uniform (e.g. driver’s license fills the whole image, they all look the same, aligned the same, etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide better constraints to this problem, currently it is far too broad. Generally yes, landmarks can prove useful for this, but imagine if your question was 'dogs' instead of 'drivers licenses'. Is [this](https://d.ibtimes.co.uk/en/full/1447148/spaghetti-and-meatballs-become-really-frightening.jpg) a picture of a dog? Which ones of [these](https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/dog-food-comparison-bagel-muffin-lookalike-teenybiscuit-karen-zack-5__700.jpg) are dogs? I think you get the point.

Comment: I don't need to determine whether or not the document is a driver's license or not.  I know for a fact that each image is a driver's license.  This implies a regularly shaped object (e.g. all driver's license's are the same size), and for each State, I will have the landmark that I need to look for known.  Let's say I have 50 NY driver's licenses, so I know where the logo is on each one, and I know what size each one should be. I want to crop, rotate, resize so that each one looks uniform after I'm done.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes! That's a much better description of the problem, so likewise you have some good suggestions now. You could consider masked feature matching, where you do feature matching from a driver's license template, but remove the features that match in personal information slots, where matched letters would not correspond properly.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (using the functionality available in OpenCV) that I can suggest is to:

1. Train a Haar Cascade Classifier to recognize the landmark (works quite well for logos)
2. Take a few rotations of the image and look for the logo in each of them. You should find one or more matches, depending on the number of rotations that you use
3. Perform edge detection and project the edge pixels to the vertical axis. The projection with largest gaps will represent the spacing between text, and lead you to select one image that is closest to the correct orientation
4. Now you can crop, zoom or un-zoom this image using the logo position using the known properties of a driving license (logo is so many inches from the top left etc.).
5. Instead of a Haar cascade classifier, you can also match SIFT features of a logo with that of the photo.

I did not post any code or examples because the question is very broad. But you can easily find OpenCV documentation and examples for each of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way in OpenCV to

1. identify in each image a known landmark: there are several ways to do it, see here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html
2. crop: yes, subset it and don't forget to copyTo [Select a subset of a Mat and copy them to create a new mat in C++/Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691079/select-a-subset-of-a-mat-and-copy-them-to-create-a-new-mat-in-c-opencv)
3. resize, rotate each image so that for the final result, I have a set
   of images that are completely uniform: you should use transformations like shown here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

this tutorial should be useful for you: https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/